# Find ROW and replace data in CSV

Tags: powershell

I have CSv file with 3 colunms .

I would to find a word in the first colunms and change the data at the same row but colunm 3

I have tried with Where-Object { $_.distinguishedName -like "*Jule*"} and I can change the data in row 3(givenName) but the rest off the file is lost .

```
DistinguishedName                      Enabled GivenName                                                                                                                 
-----------------                      ------- ---------                                                                                                                 
CN=Jule lacroix,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com True    01000000d0
CN=Marc la,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com      False   Martin
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to loop through your data with a `foreach` loop. Then make changes to each row that meets the criteria:

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv -Path File.csv

foreach ($row in $CSVData) {
    if ($row.DistinguishedName -like "*Jule*") {
       $row.GivenName = "New Name"
    }
}
$CSVData # Will contain the updated data
```

Comment: it's working but I have also a new colunm the name of this colunm is NAME .
I don't know why

Comment: If you have a new column called name, your CSV file must have had the column already. Is your CSV comma delimited or does it use some other delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking since 2 hours and i found the solution

I found this solution on another forum thank you **cduff**

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\jule\Documents\test\save.csv

$modified = ForEach ($user in $csv) {

    If($user.distinguishedName -like "*s*") {
        #New-ADUser

        $user.GivenName = 'lokil'
    }

    $user

}

$modified
```

Someone can explain the utility of $user between }} ?

thank you

Comment: `$user` is a reference variable to an object in the collection `$csv`. Since you are using a `foreach` loop, `$user` starts at the first element/index in `$csv`, which is the same as `$csv[0]`. After each loop iteration, `$user` will point to the next indexed item in `$csv`. The second value would be `$csv[1]`. Since it is a pointer or reference, when you update `$user` it also updates `$csv[index]`.

Comment: I almost found the solution by myself ,but this } $user } was missing and it's for this reason my script was not worked  .If I understood  correctly it's necessary to put $user alone ?

Comment: Assigning the output of the whole foreach to the **new** variable `$modified` makes it necessary to explicitly output **all** `$User` (after modifying them), otherwise the new var would be empty as assigning a value to a variable doesn't generate an output.